# From which version of Windows child windows can have transparency?

Tags: windows, transparency

```
 SetWindowLong (handle, GWL_EXSTYLE, GetWindowLong (h, GWL_EXSTYLE ) | WS_EX_LAYERED );
 SetLayeredWindowAttributes(h, 0, 180, 2);
```

On XP this will only work if `handle` is floating window with no parent (you can think of it as being inserted into desktop).

The more full answer would include a list of Windows-family operating systems on the left, and can it support transparent child controls on the right.

From which version of Windows child windows can have transparency?

Comment: the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633540(v=vs.10).aspx) says that `SetLayeredWindowAttributes` is supported from windows 2000

Comment: but this only works for main window, not for children.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633540%28v=vs.10%29.aspx):

> Windows 8:  The WS_EX_LAYERED style is supported for top-level windows and child windows. Previous Windows versions support WS_EX_LAYERED only for top-level windows.